# Twilio voice recognition is repeating text but not matching it

Tags: twilio, speech-recognition, voice

Im sure this is a fairly basic question. I have completed the example https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/06/how-to-use-twilio-speech-recognition.html and when I run it and I say either cat, number or chuck facts it repeats exactly what I have said perfectly but says that it cant match up with the switch statement. Has anyone experienced this before and if so could they let me know where to look.

Additionally I have also set up a basic IVR using studio flow and that also doesnt accept the speech

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Steve

Comment: It would be best to try to `console.log` what the `event.SpeechResult.toLowerCase()` actually says (you can enable live logs from within the Twilio Functions UI). I wonder if there's some extra white-space in there, for example. You could try `const command = event.SpeechResult.toLowerCase().trim();` to ensure that white-space isn't causing you trouble.